# PIVOT for value by reported date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I'm trying to use pivot to accomplish the following:

The data in the source table looks like:

| Company | Company ID | Product Code | Product Unit | Reporting Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | dd | gln | 2019 | 7 |
| a | 1 | dd | gln | 2020 | 2 |
| b | 2 | bb | kg | 2021 | 3 |

The data in the pivoted table should look like:

| Company | Company ID | Product Code | Product Unit | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | dd | gln | 7 | 2 |  |
| b | 2 | bb | kg |  |  | 3 |

I tried and it did not work:

select * from source
pivot
(
max(value) for year in
(2019,2020,2021)
);

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for your `source` table; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for your sample data; and the full text of the error. There is a mismatch between the header in your table where the column is named `Reporting Year` and your query where it is `year`; one of those is in error and we need to know how you created the table to give an accurate solution. The simplest answer is you have a typo and are using the wrong name but just saying "I tried and it did not work" does not help to debug it and we need more information.

Answer (score 2):

Change `year` to `reportingyear` and your code appears to work:

```sql
select * from source pivot ( max(value) for reportingyear in (2019,2020,2021) );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE source ( Company, CompanyID, ProductCode, ProductUnit, ReportingYear, Value ) AS
SELECT 'a', 1, 'dd', 'gln', 2019, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 1, 'dd', 'gln', 2020, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 2, 'bb', 'kg', 2021, 3 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | COMPANY | COMPANYID | PRODUCTCODE | PRODUCTUNIT | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | b | 2 | bb | kg | *<null>* | *<null>* | 3 |
> | a | 1 | dd | gln | 7 | 2 | *<null>* |

If you are using quoted identifiers and have a space in the column name then you need to use a quoted identifier every time you refer to that column:

```sql
select * from source pivot ( max(value) for "Reporting Year" in (2019,2020,2021) );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=509819a55b58a5514c7ed387d7383854)*

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select Company, Company_ID, Product_Code, Product_Unit,
       sum(case when year = 2019 then value else 0 end) as val_2019,
       sum(case when year = 2020 then value else 0 end) as val_2020,
       sum(case when year = 2021 then value else 0 end) as val_2021
from source
group by Company, Company_ID, Product_Code, Product_Unit;
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to specify all the years within the *PIVOT* clause's list by using a dynamical code structure , *assuming that you have only those three year values within the table currently, and propagate to the new pivoted columns along with the newly inserted upcoming year values* through creating a stored function such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fn_Pivot_Table RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);   
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( ReportingYear  , ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ReportingYear )                 
    INTO v_cols
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ReportingYear FROM source );
      
  v_sql :='SELECT * 
             FROM source
            PIVOT(
                   MAX(Value) FOR ReportingYear IN (' || v_cols ||' ) 
                  ) 
            ORDER BY CompanyID';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

which might be invoked from the SQL Developer's console as

```
SQL> DECLARE
    result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :result := Fn_Pivot_Table;
END;
/

SQL> PRINT result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
select * from source pivot ( max(Value) for "Reporting Year" in (2019,2020,2021) );
```

Please note that Oracle does not allow column names with spaces, so the space there should be replaced with an underscore, for example.

Thus, the query would be:

```
select * from source pivot ( max(Value) for "Reporting_Year" in (2019,2020,2021) );
```